# How to check checkboxs based on text string HTML/JS

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Is it possible to check checkbox based on string text using js or jQuery:

```js
$(':checkbox').filter(function() {
  return $(this).parent().next('label').text() === 'Text 1';
}).prop('checked', true);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label class="selectit"><input value="171" type="checkbox" name="post_category[]" id="in-category-171">Text 1</label>
<label class="selectit"><input value="172" type="checkbox" name="post_category[]" id="in-category-172">Text 2</label>
<label class="selectit"><input value="173" type="checkbox" name="post_category[]" id="in-category-173">Text 3</label>
```

([JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nz0b5or6/))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A JS example. It grabs the labels, finds the label with the text you pass in as an argument to the function, and if that label is found checks it's corresponding checkbox.

```js
function checkBoxFromLabelText(str) {

  // Select all the labels and coerce the array-like node-list
  // into an array
  const labels = [...document.querySelectorAll('label')];

  // `find` the label with the text content you supplied
  // as a string argument to the function
  const label = labels.find(label => label.textContent.trim() === str);

  // If it exists find the label's checkbox and check it
  if (label) label.querySelector('[type="checkbox"]').checked = true;

}

checkBoxFromLabelText('Text 1');
```

```html
<label class="selectit"><input value="171" type="checkbox" name="post_category[]" id="in-category-171">Text 1</label>
<label class="selectit"><input value="172" type="checkbox" name="post_category[]" id="in-category-172">Text 2</label>
<label class="selectit"><input value="173" type="checkbox" name="post_category[]" id="in-category-173">Text 3</label>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is almost there, you just need to remove `next('label')` as `parent()` already gives you a reference to the `label`.

Also note that you can make the code a little more succinct with an arrow function:

```js
$(':checkbox').filter((i, el) => $(el).parent().text().trim() === 'Text 1').prop('checked', true);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label class="selectit"><input value="171" type="checkbox" name="post_category[]" id="in-category-171">Text 1</label>
<label class="selectit"><input value="172" type="checkbox" name="post_category[]" id="in-category-172">Text 2</label>
<label class="selectit"><input value="173" type="checkbox" name="post_category[]" id="in-category-173">Text 3</label>
```

Comment: Sir, I Try it with the same HTML code [here](https://jsfiddle.net/espqxyct/) but is not working, what I need to solve it

Comment: @EnigmaOs In your jsfiddle you have two separate form elements wrapped in the same `<label>` element; log the text you're trying to compare against and you'll see its `.text()` actually returns " text 1Make Term Primary".

Comment: (You're also going to have whitespace trouble; reformatting the HTML could insert  or remove spaces that will break that text matching.  Use `trim()` as suggested in Rory's answer, or better yet put a real identifier attribute on these things instead of trying to match against user-visible strings.)